# Proper exception handling

Tags: java, exception

Lets say we have two classes `Connector` and `Main.` First one has method `connect();` and another has `actionListener()` at the button. The `Connector.connect()` may throw an `exception`. I'm not sure where is the proper place to handle this; in `Connector` or in `Main` in general? If we programming android, is it the same place to put `logs` ?

Edit:
Great article covering above problem:
https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/04/exceptions.html

Comment: Throw it or re-throw as a custom exception from Connector to Main. Logging is optional and useful thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much better to throw the exception to the user level if you want the user to know about the exact exception. Otherwise if it is not that important and the exception can be recovered then you can handle it in `Connector` itself and return some value representing error.

If the exception being thrown from the Connector is not inline with the abstraction level of Main method, then wrap it around an exception that is inline with the caller's abstraction level.

*[Throw early and catch late](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/04/exceptions.html) is the general rule for exception handling.*

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the kind of actions of the handler. If you need to show a message to the user, handle the exception in the view layer (guess it´s Connector in your case). If you need to do actions with the database (for example, a rollbak), handle it in the persistence layer.